# How to use Docker swarm mode in WSL 2

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-swarm-mode

I am trying to use [WSL 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) to do hands-on experiments on Docker swarm mode. However, when I use `docker swarm init`, it initializes the current node as the manager and provides a token to join `worker`. However, when I am trying to use the command to join worker, it is throwing an error as:

> Error response from daemon: This node is already part of a swarm. Use "docker swarm leave" to leave this swarm and join another one.

How can I configure WSL 2 to use Docker swarm mode?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the join command to join the cluster? Are you using it on another WSL instance? You obviously cannot join the master from the master machine.

1. Check which nodes already joined, if any:
   `docker node ls`
2. If the error is thrown on the worker (not the master) try to leave `docker swarm leave` and then join again.
3. Make sure you have the right `<manager-node-ip>:<port>` configuration

Comment: these are steps i followed

```docker swarm init``` in one of the wsl instance

open another terminal and jused command to join worker. I got the error. i even tried two different distro one ubuntu and kali linux. even for that i received error.